# Getting error to generate Signed Apk from Android Studio

Tags: java, android

While generating signed apk from Android Studio getting an error. A few days later all works good, while from last 2 days I am facing problem to generate signed apk.

Error is:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. What went wrong:   A problem
>   was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'. File
>   '/media/user86/data/MySIPonline/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-release-stripped.ap_'
>   specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.

I've checked that folder and release-stripped.ap file is present in it. I am not able to figure out the error.

Here is `build.gradle` (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'de.petendi:ethereum-android-lib:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'org.ethereum:ethereumj-core:1.2.0-RELEASE'
    testCompile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.1-1'
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0'
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.1'
    }
}
```

Here is link for pro-guard file - https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/b667326812b87702c86fa02870b28240

Please help and thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Pratik Tank, I did but getting same issue is there any thing else?

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: i did but still getting same error